# ViewPageIndicator Force Close Issue

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-activity, viewpagerindicator

I have this logcat and I have no idea what's my error. I have no clue where is my error here.

http://pastebin.com/jzCZKWKG <-- LOGCAT

I'm using viewpage indicator with adapter. Here's my Code

**Activity3**

```
package com.example.jcw;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

import com.viewpagerindicator.UnderlinePageIndicator;

public class activity3 extends Activity 
{


    ViewPager viewPager;
    PagerAdapter adapter;
    int[] flag;
    String[] rank;
    UnderlinePageIndicator mIndicator;




    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.app3);


       rank = new String[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14" };


       flag = new int[] { R.drawable.gr, R.drawable.calvitcdetails,
               R.drawable.barleydetails, R.drawable.hilifedetails,
               R.drawable.kapedetails, R.drawable.glutafitdetails, R.drawable.omnidaydetails,
               R.drawable.omnipinkishdetails, R.drawable.omnisoapdetails, R.drawable.omnitonerdetails
               , R.drawable.organicbarleyjuicedetails, R.drawable.pgtdetails, R.drawable.shuyadetails 
               , R.drawable.spirulinadetails };

    // Locate the ViewPager in viewpager_main.xml
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    // Pass results to ViewPagerAdapter Class
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(activity3.this, flag , rank);
    // Binds the Adapter to the ViewPager
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    // ViewPager Indicator
    mIndicator = (UnderlinePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    mIndicator.setFades(false);
    mIndicator.setViewPager(viewPager);




    }






}
```

**ViewPageAdapter**

```
  package com.example.jcw;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

    public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        // Declare Variables
        Context context;
        int[] flag;
        String[] rank;
        LayoutInflater inflater;

        public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context,  int[] flag, String[] rank) {
            this.flag = flag;
            this.rank = rank;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return rank.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

            ImageView imgflag;

            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.app3x, container,
                    false);



            // Locate the ImageView in viewpager_item.xml
            imgflag = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            // Capture position and set to the ImageView
            imgflag.setImageResource(flag[position]);

            // Add viewpager_item.xml to ViewPager
            ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);

            return itemView;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            // Remove viewpager_item.xml from ViewPager
            ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);

        }
    }
```

app3 XML

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <com.viewpagerindicator.UnderlinePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

app3x XML

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp" >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:padding="1dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`context` is null in `ViewPagerAdapter`, causing a `NullPointerException` at:

```
 inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Change your constructor as follows:

```
public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, int[] flag, String[] rank) {
    this.context = context;
    this.flag = flag;
    this.rank = rank;
}
```

You've also got an incorrect ID for the ImageView. Change:

```
 imgflag = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

to:

```
 imgflag = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flag);
```

Comment: I got followup though. I tried it with a samsung galaxy tablet 10 when I open this activity it just gives me white screen and did not show content. How come?

Comment: Is it specific to that device? I mean, have you tried it in an emulator or on another device?

Comment: Tried it with my LG G2 it worked but when I tried with a larger screen and on landscape content does not show up just white page

Comment: I couldn't say, then. I've only one device to test on, and that code works on it. Are you sure you don't have separate layouts for portrait and landscape? Maybe the landscape layout is off?

Comment: I have layout for them like layout-sw600dp-land and layout-sw800dp-land

Comment: Dunno. You might temporarily remove all but the one layout that you know works, and see if that gives you any clues.